# How can I enter actual text (like real keyboard strokes) via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to create a script for auto login of this website. I already managed to have it entered in the input boxes but upon clicking Log In button it seems that it didn't read my input. An error keep saying email address and password is required. But if I manually type in the credentials it's ok, I was able to login or a different error msg will be prompted for incorrect credentials.

I think the website still reads it as placeholder and not the actual text value?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sUrl As String: sUrl = "https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/RealTimeMonitoring"
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objNode As Object
    'Dim inputElement As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate sUrl

    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set inputCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    Set colNodes = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-block investa-login--btn-login btn-investa__medium--blue btn-investa__medium")

    For Each inputElement In inputCollection

        If inputElement.getAttribute("data-ng-model") = "LoginRequest.Username" Then
        inputElement.Click
        inputElement.Value = "test98@yahoo.com"
        End If

        If inputElement.getAttribute("data-ng-model") = "LoginRequest.Password" Then
        inputElement.Click
        inputElement.Value = "test"

        End If
    Next inputElement
    For Each objNode In colNodes
        If objNode.getAttribute("data-ng-click") = "authenticateUser()" Then
        objNode.Click
        End If
    Next objNode


End Sub
```

```
Email Input Box
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" data-ng-disabled="IsLoading" 
data-ng-model="LoginRequest.Username" data-on-enter-keydown-directive="authenticateUser()" 
required="required" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="40" style="">

Password Input Box
<input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength 
ng-touched" placeholder="Password" data-ng-disabled="IsLoading" 
data-ng-model="LoginRequest.Password" data-on-enter-keydown-directive="authenticateUser()" required="required" maxlength="40" style="">
```

Comment: Have a look at Application.SendKeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this page seems to use jQuery you can use that to simulate the events on the page a lot easier than with the current method.

```
Sub Sample()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/RealTimeMonitoring"

        Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        .document.parentWindow.execScript "$('form input:eq(0)').val('MyUserName').change();"
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "$('form input:eq(1)').val('MyPassword').change();"
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "$('form button').click();"
        Stop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will look into this and apply for other jQuery pages that I may be working on.

Comment: If this has been helpful, consider voting, or marking this as complete if this answered your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers